# How to count value in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have trouble in counting values in laravel 8. I want to count all in the table
below that have in and doesnt have a status out yet. How to count value that is doesnt have status out in laravel eloquent it is group by member_Code

[image: This is the table that i want to count that doesnt have out]

Comment: `Model::where('status','!=','out')->count()`

Comment: I mean i want to count all status that have 'in' value in the table and doesnt have out. In short i want to count all member that dont time out yet @KamleshPaul

Answer (score 2):

you can count using `DB::raw` like this:

```
  $values=   MyModel::query()->where('status', '!=', 'out')
            ->select(['member_Code',DB::raw('count(*)')]) ->groupBy('member_Code')->get();
```

if you want  to count all member that don't time out yet, you can use [distinct](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_distinct) method:

```
 $inMemebersCount= MyModel::query()->where('status', '!=', 'out')
            ->select('member_Code')->distinct()->count();
```

Comment: hey i think he want count of each `member_Code`

Comment: I mean i want to count all status that have 'in' value in the table and doesnt have out. In short i want to count all member that dont time out yet @KamleshPaul

Comment: @KamleshPaul , hey, how you doing? thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

The simple eloquent solution would be to use `count()` method like

```
Model::where('status', '!=', 'out')->count();
```

But what do you mean by group by? Do you want the count of each group?

Comment: I mean i want to count all status that have 'in' value in the table and doesnt have out. In short i want to count all member that dont time out yet

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$data = Model::where('status', '!=', 'out')->group_by('member_Code')->get();
$count = count($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$memberCode = 'G-51405';
$membersCount = Member::where('status','in')->where('member_code', $memberCode)->count();
```