# how to count value in laravel 8 eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to count member that has been time in each day but dont have a time out yet. In short i want to count member in particular date that doesnt have time out. This is because i want to count all the member inside the compound for safety guidelines.  For example G-51405 been time in but no time out in the table, G-51405 will be counted because he/she dont have a time out yet and so on..

[image: here is the table]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count value in Laravel Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66649811/how-to-count-value-in-laravel-eloquent)

Answer (score -1):

```
$memberCode = 'G-51405';
$membersCount = Member::where('status','in')->where('member_code', $memberCode)->count();
```